# numpy array:tuple index out of range

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv, google-colaboratory

```
#converting the lists into numpy arrays
x_train=np.array(x_train)
x_test=np.array(x_test)
y_train=np.array(y_train)
y_test=np.array(y_test)
x_train.shape,x_test.shape,y_train.shape,y_test.shape
```

> the problem starts from below code

## reshaping into 2d to save in csv format

```
x_train_2d=np.reshape(x_train,(x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1]*x_train.shape[2]))
x_test_2d=np.reshape(x_test,(x_test.shape[0],x_test.shape[1]*x_test.shape[2]))
x_train_2d.shape,x_test_2d.shape
```

Comment: what is the original shape of the arrays?

Comment: Post the error output too

Comment: the shape of numpy array _train.shape,x_test.shape,y_train.shape,y_test.shape is ((7895, 40), (837, 40), (7895,), (837,))

Comment: the error formed is:         IndexError      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-758431749d1f> in <module>()
----> 1 x_train_2d=np.reshape(x_train,(x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1]*x_train.shape[2]))
      2 x_test_2d=np.reshape(x_test,(x_test.shape[0],x_test.shape[1]*x_test.shape[2]))
      3 x_train_2d.shape,x_test_2d.shape

IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: what should be the output shape.

Comment: you are getting index error because you are accessing `shape[2]` and shape is a tuple of two elements.

Comment: i just want to save the numpy array as csv(2-d)

Comment: @abhilb can you please explain it

Comment: It is already a two d array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what you can do is the following.

Create a csv file with columns `40 values from second dimension of X, and Y value`
Rows will be training data first followed by test data

```
data_train = np.c_[x_train, y_train]
data_test = np.c_[x_test, y_test]
data = np.r_[data_train, data_test]
print(data.shape)
np.savetxt('filename.csv', data, delimiter=',')
```

Output data shape will be

`(8732, 41)`